# Вставка элементов в список чисел

Tags: pascal

Помогите написать на Pascal задачу.

Пусть L - список целых чисел. Описать процедуру, которая включает в список число 0 за первым отрицательным числом. Если в L нет отрицательных чисел, список не менять.

Трудность, для меня, состоит в том, как создать звено с нулём и включить его в список после отрицательного элемента...

```
type list=^elem;  
elem=record data:integer; next:list; end;

procedure otr(l:list);  
  var f:boolean;p:list;  
begin  
  f:=false;p:=l;  
  while (p<>nil)and not f do  
    if p^.data<0 then   
      begin
        {Вот здесь не знаю как написать}  
      end  
    else
      p:=p^.next;
end;
```

Comment: Вы не знаете, как создать экземпляр `elem`? Разумеется, динамически, при помощи `new`. Дальше сможете?

Comment: Я не знаю, как создать новое звено и вставить его в список, после первого отрицательного, так чтобы связь между ссылками не порвалась.  
Можете написать?

Comment: @mango44, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Единственная хитрость в вашей задаче — это то, что надо вставить *перед* найденным элементом. Для этого вам нужно иметь указатель на звено вместо самого звена.

```
procedure otr(var l: list); { var обязателен! }
  var curr: ^list;
      savednext: list;
begin
  curr := @list;
  while (curr^ <> nil) do  
    if curr^^.data < 0 then   
      begin
        savednext := curr^^.next;
        new(curr^);
        curr^^.data := 0;
        curr^^.next := savednext;
        break;
      end  
    else
      curr := @(curr^^.next);
end;
```

Надеюсь, я не ошибся с синтаксисом паскаля, давно не практиковался.